# Django Ckeditor and Youtube plugin not working

Tags: django

9 in my blog app and i'm trying to configure Youtube plugin for this i've tried to use many different tutorials on YT and similar solutrions from here and nothing wokred maybe there is another way to paste YT movie into my blog post?

**settings.py**

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'toolbar': 'Custom',
    'width': 'auto',
    'toolbar_Custom': [
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Link']
    ],
},
'special': {
    'toolbar': 'Special',
    'width': 'auto',
    'toolbar_Special': [
      ['Image','CodeSnippet', 'Youtube']
    ],
    'extraPlugins': ','.join(['codesnippet','youtube'])
}
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content = RichTextUploadingField(null=True)
contentmedia = RichTextUploadingField(null=True,
                                      config_name='special',
                                      blank=True,
                                      external_plugin_resources=
                                      [('youtube', '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/youtube/', 'plugin.js')], )
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**config.js**

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.language = 'fr';
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
config.width = "auto";
config.display = "block";
config.extraPlugins = 'youtube';

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Django can't view your static files that contain the plugin itself. In settings.py comment the line with STATIC_ROOT ( uncomment it when you need to register it in the collectstatic console ) and add the lines:
STATIC_DIR= os. path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS=[STATIC_DIR]